# Вырезать часть в объекте

Tags: php

Допустим есть ссылка https://instagram.com/heavenly
heavenly - это пример, ники будут разные. Как мне вырезать https://instagram.com/ и оставить только ник?

Comment: хоть одна идея то у вас родилась в голове? можно, например, заменить `https://instagram.com/` на пустую строку, можно удалить первые 22 или сколько там символа, можно регулярками вытянуть.

Comment: @ДенисНебесный `'~https?://instagram.com/(\w+)~'` а вторым параметром в preg_replace() подставить ссылку на подмаску `'$1'`

Comment: @teran  ну а если будет указано http вместо https получается удалится 1-й символ ника

Comment: дак вы и задачу описываете со всеми своими _если_

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать несколькими методами, например использовать `parse_url` или `str_replace`

```
<?php
// 1 способ
$url = 'https://instagram.com/heavenly';
$replace1 = parse_url($url);
print_r($replace1['path']);

// 2 способ
$replace2 = str_replace('https://instagram.com/','',$url);
print_r($replace2);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$url = 'https://instagram.com/heavenly';
echo basename($url); // heavenly
```

Answer (score 0):

еще пару вариантов

```
$url = "https://instagram.com/heavenly";

$result[] = str_ireplace("https://instagram.com/", "", $url);

$result[] = array_pop(explode('/', $url));

$result[] = substr($url, 22);

$result[] = preg_replace("/(.*\/)/i", "",  $url);

preg_match("/([^\/]+)$/i", $url, $m);
$result[] = $m[1];

$result[] = trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');

$result[] = sscanf($url, "https://instagram.com/%s")[0];


print_r($result);
```

среди всего вышеперечисленного, лучше всего вам, очевидно, подойдет `parse_url`

Comment: вот эта строка `array_pop(explode('/', $url));`, насколько я помню, вызовет strict standart, т.к. array_pop() принимает аргумент по ссылке.

Comment: @Эдуард да, согласен. можно `explode()[0]` сделать